# How do I read a string sent from PHP through a socket to a Qt server application?

Tags: php, c++, qt, sockets

I am having a really hard time reading character input that is sent through a socket connection to a Qt server application. The data is sent from PHP.

I understand the principles of reading streamdata because I already asked this on stack. I also got it working using a server and client written both in Qt.

The method I use is to append the bytesize of the data i want to send before the actual data. Then when the data comes in, I first read the length parth so that I know exactly how much bytes I have to read in order to have correctly formed data.

it looks like this:

send function:

```
void Client::sendNewMessage(){
    qDebug() << "sendNewMessage()";

    QString string(messageLineEdit->text());

    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    out << quint16(0);
    out  << string;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    tcpSocket->write(block);
}
```

receive function:

```
QDataStream in(tcpServerConnection);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
qDebug() << "bytes available = " << tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable();

if (blockSize == 0) {
    int size = (int) sizeof(quint16);
    qDebug() << "size = " << size;
    if (tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16)){
        qDebug() << "less bytes than size...";
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "bytes available=" << tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable();
    in >> blockSize;
}

if (tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable() < blockSize){
    qDebug() << "less bytes available than blocksize, bytes="
                   << tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable();
    return;
}

QString data;
in >> data;
qDebug() << "data = " << data;
```

Okay, this all works so I tried doing it with PHP but it failed

this is one of my attempts:

```
<?php

$addr = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

$client = stream_socket_client("tcp://$addr:*****", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($client === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Failed to connect: $errorMessage");
}

$data = 'a';
$datatopost = serialize($data);

fwrite($client, strlen($data));
fwrite($client, base64_encode($data));
echo stream_get_contents($client);
fclose($client);
```

In Qt I have tried various combinations of quint8, 16, 32, 64, sizeof(char), sizeof(int).

in PHP I have tried serializing the data, encoding it, and also sending it without all that stuff. But i can not get it to work. I must be very close though because the data is actually sent as there are bytes available but I have no idea how to encode/decode correctly for it to work.

After asking various question concerning this topic I do feel that my understanding has gone up a lot but an important piece of information on how to actually do things is still missing for me.

**So my question: What is going wrong here and what steps need to be taken to be able to read data from PHP to Qt/C++?**

Details are highly apreciated as I really like to know how things work from the inside out.

**side-note** after sending data from the PHP script, the server sends data back aswel and that works. So the connection is made succesfuly

**UPDATE**
this is the working php script that actually also receives a reply back:

```
<?php

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    perror("Could not create socket");
}
echo "Socket created n";

//Connect socket to remote server
if(!socket_connect($sock , '127.0.0.1' , *****))
{
    perror("Could not connect");
}
echo "Connection established n";

$message = "aa";
//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    perror("Could not send data");
}
echo "Message send successfully n";

//Now receive reply from server
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 500 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
{
    perror("Could not receive data");
}
echo $buf;

///Function to print socket error message
function perror($msg)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("$msg: [$errorcode] $errormsg n");
}
```

The script reply when executed from browser url:

```
Socket created nConnection established nMessage send successfully n hello
```

Comment: QDataStream expects a special encoding for the data. Are you sure your PHP code is reading/writing data in the QDataStream 4.0 format? Otherwise both ends are seeing garbage...

Comment: @tux3          well, i definitely have not specified any QDataStream format in PHP. Although the php script does echo the data that the server sends back. The code i posted above is edited a little again, so as of right now the php script is not receiving back any data. But i am sure a small edit will fix that. The server does receive bytes, I dont know if that is enough. I am kind of getting lost in all the various things I have tried that i forget to document the things that work 100%

Comment: @tux3 i updated my post

Comment: @SaZ           hmm? how is QNetworkAccessManager going to solve my problem? :p

Comment: Nevermind. I was wrong. I'm not sure, that you should use `QDataStream` for reading. Instead - create your own protocol, for example - first 8 bytes = size of packet, then send raw data. And read in directly, with `QIODevice::read` method (it's reimplemented in `QTcpSocket`).

Comment: @SaZ           Hmmm sounds good, Ill go check that out but why is QDataStream not the way to go for reading in this case?

Comment: Because `QDataStream` implements it's own serialization protocol. If you want to use `QDataStream`, take a look at `readRawData` and `writeRawData` methods.

Comment: @SaZ           hmmmm well, that clears things up a bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SaZ           By the way, if I were to use your example protocol. Would I have to somehow encode the data in PHP before i write it to the socket? I am still pretty new to this part of programming.

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I can't help. Just beware mistakes with size of types and with byte order (big/littile endian).

Comment: @SaZ           Ill keep that in mind,, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that surprising the PHP code does not integrate. As mentioned you have to be aware that QDataStream implements a custom serialization. And as also mentioned you probably want to use [(read|write)RawData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#readRawData), or [(read|write)Bytes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#readBytes), if your reading something not previously serialized with QDataStream in general. However, the general idea of the way your trying to write string data from PHP *should* be compatible with the way Qt encodes strings (length then a series of characters. That is what the manual says anyway..). But there some issues.

- [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#details) is 2Byte Unicode.
- PHP Strings are byte arrays of an arbitrary kind of ASCII compatible data - [PHP String details](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details).
- There is a few things wrong with this bit:

  ```
  fwrite($client, strlen($data));
  fwrite($client, base64_encode($data));
  ```

  `strlen()` returns the number of bytes in the underlying storage (which is the actual byte length for a ASCII string). base64_encode() changes the number of bytes in the string. And your assuming fwrite() is writing a four byte integer. Its type casting and writing a string.
- We are still guessing at how

  ```
  QString data; 
  in >> data;
  ```

  really works.

General advice is, you've got to carefully define external binary APIs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain in detail but I am wondering now why people mention I should be using readRawData even though hank showed me in his answer that such a simple solution does work indeed.

Comment: nevermind what i said, I did not realise that readRawData simply reads the bytes without any encoding. I assume thats the same as QTcpSocket::readAll which also reads the raw data

Comment: Yep that's right. @hank's solution works (and is more elegant), because it's not making false assumptions about data formats. Its just reading/writing raw bytes. If you want to do something with the data you receive other than print it to screen or echo it back to the sender, then you need to start worrying about getting everyone agreeing on how the data is encoded etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need data serialization for this task at all? Your PHP client and Qt server are probably using different formats for it.
Try to send and receive raw data.

Here is a simple `QTcpServer` exmaple:

```
class DataReceiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataReceiver(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void start(quint16 port = 9090);

private slots:
    void newTcpConnection();

private:
    QTcpServer server;
};

DataReceiver::DataReceiver(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newTcpConnection()));
}

void DataReceiver::start(quint16 port)
{
    bool isOk = server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);

    if (isOk && server.isListening())
    {
        qDebug() << "QTcpServer started on port" << port;
    }
    else
    {
        qCritical() << "Failed to start QTcpServer";
    }
}

void DataReceiver::newTcpConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "New incoming connection";

    QTcpSocket *socket = server.nextPendingConnection();

    QByteArray data;

    while (true)
    {
        QByteArray tmp = socket->readAll();
        data += tmp;

        if (tmp.isEmpty() && !socket->waitForReadyRead())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    socket->deleteLater();

    qDebug("Data received: %s (len = %d)", data.constData(), data.length());
}
```

Launching server:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "data_receiver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    DataReceiver d;
    d.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

You can use a PHP client to send data to it:

```
<?php

$addr = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
$port = 9090;
$data = 'hello from php';

$client = stream_socket_client("tcp://$addr:$port", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($client === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Failed to connect: $errorMessage");
}

fwrite($client, $data);
fclose($client);
```

Or you can use the `nc` utility:

```
echo -n "hello from nc" | nc 127.0.0.1 9090
```

Here is server output for both cases:

```
QTcpServer started on port 9090 
New incoming connection 
Data received: hello from php (len = 14)
New incoming connection 
Data received: hello from nc (len = 13)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works even though people tell me I should use readRawData?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything I don't know why you need to use `QDataStream` when you can read data directly from a `QTcpSocket` object.

Comment: neither am I lol. I am still a greenie at programming and I saw all those examples using QDataStream. And as it is a stream of bytes that is being sent I thought QDataStream would be a common thing to use for this kind of stuff... apparently I was wrong.

Comment: In the first place `QDataStream` should be used for serialization/deserialization tasks. [The docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) explicitly says that: _The QDataStream class provides serialization of binary data to a QIODevice_. If you just need to read some raw data from a device, `QIODevice::readAll()` is completely fine.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense,, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: I decided ti give the bounty to S.Pinkus, simply because his answer explained more in detail about what was going on. You did give my a running example so I thank you for that!